# TypeError: 'AnchorLayout' object is not callable kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

Some days ago code perfectly worked. Today, i've got TypeError when trying to start my program.

```
TypeError: 'AnchorLayout' object is not callable kivy python
```

What's wrong?

```
class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.password = TextInput(text='', password=True, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None)  # Обьявление пароля
        self.username = TextInput(text='', multiline=False, size_hint_y=None)  # Обьявление логина

    @property
    def build(self):
        al: AnchorLayout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center',anchor_y='center')

        al.add_widget(Label(text='Login'))

        al.add_widget(self.username)
        al.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))

        al.add_widget(self.password)
        al.add_widget(Button(text='Войти', on_press=self.login))
        return al

    def login(self, instance):
        username = print(self.username.text)
        password = print(self.password.text)
        s = cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM drivers WHERE username='"+str(username)+"'")
        for x in cursor:
            print(x)
        if password == s:
            print('Success')
```

Comment: You will need to add the full error stacktrace. How are we supposed to know where the error happens?

Comment: `al: AnchorLayout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center',anchor_y='center')` doesn't make sense.
Use `al = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center',anchor_y='center')` instead...

Comment: @embryo yes it makes sense, it is part of typing in python 3. read https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @eyllanesc Xmm, I didn't know that.
Thanks for the heads up!